# startup problems Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I am running Ubuntu 16.04. Recently the monitor started to flash the startup screen and then go black. After running for a few minutes, I could restart the computer and I would get a normal startup and it would run perfectly until later shutdown for the day. Thinking it was a graphics card problem, I replaced my EVGA card with a EVGA GT730 card. The card was old and probably needed replacing anyway. I have a 600w PS so that should not be the problem. I do no gaming. I am still having the same problem with the screen going black at startup. All help appreciated.

Comment: What you mean with going black ? When? Howlong? What is the last screen you see ? What did you do before you had this problem ?

Comment: Screen flashes startup screen and then nothing. Black screen.  If i let it run for about 30 min and restart it runs fine call day. This just started about a week ago and I thought it it may be my old graphics card so replaced card. Still acts same way. I did nothing that I know of to cause this.

Answer (score 0):

## **While booting**

Press “e” to get into edit mode. then look for the line containing ”

**Change this line :**

```
.... quiet splash ....
```

**To this line :**

```
.... quiet splash nomodeset ........
```

**Press ctrl + x and continue booting**

**To make it persistent :**

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

**Change this line :**

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash”
```

**To this line :**

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash nomodeset″
```

**Save file and update grub :**

```
sudo update-grub
```

**Reboot** :

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Did not work. only magnified the screen so I could not see entire screen.